# DownloadType for UnsampledReport in the google analytics api SDK

Tags: google-analytics

The UnsampledReport class in the google analytics api SDK has a method on it setDownloadType that takes a string as a parameter.

https://mavenbrowse.pauldoo.com/central/com/google/apis/google-api-services-analytics/v3-rev115-1.20.0/google-api-services-analytics-v3-rev115-1.20.0-javadoc.jar/-/com/google/api/services/analytics/model/UnsampledReport.html#setDownloadType(java.lang.String)

The value 'GOOGLE_DRIVE' tells Google to unload the report as a CSV onto a google drive path.

We want to unload the report onto a google cloud storage bucket though. We know this is possible because the UnsampledReport class also has a nested CloudStorageDownloadDetails class, but can't figure out what to pass to setDownloadType to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the [Unsampled Reports API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/unsampled-reports#retrieving_data_for_unsampled_reports) the [`downloadType`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports#resource-representations) is not writable on `insert` despite the generated client libraries creating a `setDownloadType()` method.

You will need to contact your Analytics Premium support to configure your account to propagate your generated report to either Google Drive or Cloud Storage.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks so much for your reply! We'll be contacting support and following this up. Will post at the end.